# Word wrapping strings with double quotes without a newline character

Tags: javascript

Pressing enter while writing a long string written between double quotes `" "` is not allowed in JavaScript,
I have a string like this:

```js
const myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

I want it to stay on one line when it's printed to the DOM, so I think I shouldn't use the template strings `` `these` ``, however, while coding in development, I want to see it wrapping on multiple lines in my code editor.

I can enable the option of word wrap in my text editor, however, I don't want to do that. I am just asking if there's a way to split a string into multiple lines of code so it can become clearer because I can not use the enter key like the way we do it in HTML, in HTML you can put as many spaces as you like, or as much enters as you like, but by the end, the result will not be affected, I want exactly that in javascript, is it possible?

Comment: I was also wondering if there's an option in prettier to achieve that

Comment: if the goal is only writing it to DOM, why not use template strings with linefeeds? The DOM will treat linefeeds as spaces. Unless you are escaping/changing them when writing to the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the sting into an array and then join it when you use the string:

```js
const myStr = [
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,",
  "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna",
  "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation",
  "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
  "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit",
  "esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint",
  "occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui offici",
  "deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."];

console.log(myStr.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` to put more strings together without creating `\n` (newline)

Beside that no, you cant have multiple lines in `""` or ignore new lines when using `` implicitly.

```js
const myStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." 
    + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat "
    + "nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

console.log(myStr)
```

There can be one hacky solution, where you create string with new lines and then you remove all the `\n`

```js
const myStr = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

console.log('before', myStr);
console.log('after', myStr.replaceAll('\n',''));
```